# How to decrypt string with iv in node.js without getting "Error: Invalid key length"?

Tags: node.js, encryption

I have some data I need to decrypted. It was encrypted with the 'aes-256-ctr' algorithm, my key is '77d51976-94b1-43af-83a3-9e02fe5c05c8' (obviously this is not my real key, it's just for the example!), and each piece of data has a corresponding IV.

For example, in PHP, this:

```
openssl_decrypt('PZ9qCKIi77nR', 'aes-256-ctr', '77d51976-94b1-43af-83a3-9e02fe5c05c8', 0, '4195698429565026');
```

results in the unencrypted string "client-id" as expected.

The encrypted data is then stored, and I want to unencrypt it in a node.js application. However when I run:

```
crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-256-ctr', '77d51976-94b1-43af-83a3-9e02fe5c05c8', '4195698429565026');
```

I get "Error: Invalid key length". It's not clear to my why crypto is expecting a specific length for a key, and what that length is or how to debug this.

My question is how to decipher the following dataset with node.js:

- encrypted: 'PZ9qCKIi77nR'
- algorithm: 'aes-256-ctr'
- key: '77d51976-94b1-43af-83a3-9e02fe5c05c8'
- iv: '4195698429565026'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your key is the wrong length. An AES key must be precisely 16, 24, or 32 bytes long, and should be a completely random sequence of bytes. Your key is an ASCII string that is 36 bytes long.

I suspect that `openssl_decrypt` is just ignoring the hyphens, and then hex-decoding this string into a 128 bit (16 byte) key.

I suspect that `createDecipheriv` is treating this as a UTF-8 encoded string, rather than hex-encoded, which means that even if you remove the hyphens, you will get a completely different value.

To match the PHP, you'll likely need to strip the hyphens and the hex-decode this into a Buffer or KeyObject rather than a string.